# Regex needed for renaming a specific substring in a file

Tags: regex, expression

I have a file based on xml for which I use a BAT file to find and replace a substring within the xml.

I use this code to get the system time and later use it to replace the previous time.

```
@echo off
set hr=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
set hr=%hr: =0%
@echo on
RxFind Test.txt /p:"HHmm(?<one>.*?)(?<two>.*?)(?<thr>.*?)(?<fou>.*)" /r:HHmm%hr%
```

So if I run this, I get this value in my XML:
            `< Value string="HHmm1416"/ >`
replaced by `HHmm(system time)`, so it works except for

```
Value string="HHmm1752
< / Value>
```

It cuts off the "\ > and moves the lower line  on the same line. What is the Regex to properly replace ONLY `HHmm1416` with `HHMM(new systime)` ? I can't get the expressions right.

I use RxFind for this. I got it, just use Boobs and b2 for no backup cuz

```
RxFind Test.SC2Bank.txt /p:"HHmm(.)(.)(.)(.)" /r:HHmm%hr% /b:2
```

Comment: If you solved it post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

RxFind is written in C# and uses the .NET Regular Expression formats, so use \d{4} to find 4 digits:

```
RxFind Test.txt /p:"HHmm\d{4}" /r:HHmm%hr% /b:2
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, you should add an explanation stating why/how it solves the problem.